# Are topological vector spaces completely regular?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

> - [Every uniformizable space is a completely regular topological
>   space.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniformizable_spaces)
> - [topological vector spaces are uniform spaces.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure)
> - [every Hausdorff topological vector space is completely regular.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure)

From the first two, we can say every topological vector space is completely regular, can't we?

Does a TVS need to be hausdorff in order to be completely regular?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this depends on your definitions. Some people require TVS to have the condition $T_0$, in which case they are automatically Hausdorff, so I assume you don't require this. Some people use the term completely regular to mean $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ in which case Hausdorff is needed. It seems if completely regular is the definition where you don't require Hausdorff, then it should be true.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks! (1) Could you point out what "completely regular" means in the first one and the third one? (2) Do "topological vector space" in the last two include $T_0$ in their definitions (Wiki also mentions this, but its definition doesn't assume $T_0$ in TVS definition).

Comment: In the first and second ones, *completely regular* does not include $T_0$; in the third it does (or might as well, since Hausdorff implies $T_0$).